# Programming using CMD as a beginner?

Tags: python, ide

I just start an online Python course and the first approach is using the console commands to create some files, moving around with dir, etc.

I know how to program in Java but I always used Eclipse to do my projects.

It is worth to learn how to do stuff using command lines in CMD, or it is irrelevant if we have good IDEs that we can use.

Comment: the python console become irrelevant quickly(for actual programming) ... i would recommend pycharm personally

Comment: `cmd` is a sorry excuse for a shell.  But yes, it is worth it. An IDE does too much magic for you, and you definitely don't need it as a beginner. I know many professional Python programmers who use vim and a terminal. That being said, this question is too opinion based for this format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most programmers won't generally touch the windows shell. If you are going to become an advanced programmer it is most likely that you will end up becoming familiar with the UNIX shell. Learning shell is a good idea, and if you are on the Windows platform I would recommend [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) as it allows you to learn the UNIX style shell while working in Windows.

Comment: I dont think this actually adresses the OP's actual question if you read between the lines ... as an aside you are going to have a hard time putting a definitively and demonstrable correct answer to this problem :P